# Dialogflow doesn't return training phrases

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get an overview of the training phrases per intent from Dialogflow in python.

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow_v2.services.intents.IntentsClient#google_cloud_dialogflow_v2_services_intents_IntentsClient_list_intents) example to generate the following code:

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2

# get_credentials is a custom function that loads the credentials
credentials, project_id = get_credentials()

client = dialogflow_v2.IntentsClient(credentials=credentials)

request = dialogflow_v2.ListIntentsRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{project_id}/agent/environments/draft",
)
page_result = client.list_intents(request=request)

for intent in page_result:
    print("Intent name: ", intent.name)
    print("Intent display_name: ", intent.display_name)
    print("Training phrases: ", intent.training_phrases)
```

The name and display name of the intent are printed as expected, however training phrases is always an empty list (for both the draft as the test environment). Any ideas on why I'm not seeing the training phrases that I can see in the console?

**EDIT**
After hkanjih's answer I've updated my code as follows:

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2

# get_credentials is a custom function that loads the credentials
credentials, project_id = get_credentials()

client = dialogflow_v2.IntentsClient(credentials=credentials)

request = dialogflow_v2.ListIntentsRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{project_id}/agent/environments/draft",
)
page_result = client.list_intents(request=request)

for intent in page_result:
    print("Intent name: ", intent.name)
    # intent.name is equal to projects/{project_id}/agent/intents/{intent_id}
    intent_request = dialogflow_v2.GetIntentRequest(
        name=intent.name,
    )
    intent = client.get_intent(request=intent_request)
    
    # printing intent name again just to check if it's the same (it is)
    print("Intent name: ", intent.name)
    print("Intent display_name: ", intent.display_name)
    print("Training phrases: ", intent.training_phrases)
```

Unfortunately, for all intents: `Training phrases:  []`

Comment: Have you saved training phrases after adding it? You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases) to add training phrases.

Comment: Yes, I have saved the training phrases. The model was trained and recognizes when an user-expression matches the intent.

Comment: Could you try using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494423/obtain-intents-entities-and-the-training-data-from-dialogflow-in-the-python-env/60502232#60502232) to get the list of training phrases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in the documentation some more, I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/IntentView) page. Therefore I added the `intent_view` parameter to the request as in the snippet below:

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2

# get_credentials is a custom function that loads the credentials
_credentials, project_id = self._get_credentials()

client = dialogflow_v2.IntentsClient(credentials=_credentials)

request = dialogflow_v2.ListIntentsRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{project_id}/agent/environments/draft",
    intent_view="INTENT_VIEW_FULL",
)

page_result = client.list_intents(request=request)

for intent in page_result:
    print("Intent name: ", intent.name)
    print("Intent display_name: {}", intent.display_name)
    print("Training phrases: ", intent.training_phrases)
```

Note that in the request the parent `f"projects/{project_id}/agent"` (without the environment) gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you're not seeing the training phrases because the `training_phrases` field is not populated by the `ListIntents` method.

This field is populated by the `GetIntent` method.

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2

# get_credentials is a custom function that loads the credentials
credentials, project_id = get_credentials()

client = dialogflow_v2.IntentsClient(credentials=credentials)

intent_id = "my-intent-id"

request = dialogflow_v2.GetIntentRequest(
    name=f"projects/{project_id}/agent/intents/{intent_id}",
)

intent = client.get_intent(request=request)

print("Intent name: ", intent.name)
print("Intent display_name: ", intent.display_name)
print("Training phrases: ", intent.training_phrases)
```

So, for what you need maybe you have to get the list of intend first (using `ListIntentsRequest`) and for each intent in the list you have to call `GetIntentRequest` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the training phrases are still an empty list. If you see an error in my code when reproducing your answer, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Your phrases are probably in the draft so use these references.

```
  intent_path = intent.name
     intent_request = dialogflow.GetIntentRequest(
         name=intent_path,
         language_code="pt-BR",
         intent_view=dialogflow.IntentView.INTENT_VIEW_FULL,
     )
     intent = intents_client.get_intent(request=intent_request)
```